# Memory Allocation and Try-Catch Block

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a function to allocate a 2D array in order to not to expend more memory than I need:

_>

```
template <class Xvar> Xvar** New2 (unsigned int rows,unsigned int cols)
{
    Xvar**  mem;
    unsigned int size, i;

    size = rows * cols;
    mem = new Xvar* [rows];
    mem [0] = new Xvar [size];
    for (i=1;i<rows;i++)
        mem [i] = &mem [0][i*cols];
    return mem;
}
```

Now, I need to check if that memory is allocated. (handle memory allocation errors),
without decreasing the performance of the function.

Should I use a try-catch block for each memory allocation, or  only a unique try-catch block for the function.

```
template <class Xvar> Xvar** New2 (unsigned int rows,unsigned int cols)
{
    Xvar**  mem;
    unsigned int size, i;

    size = rows * cols;
    try {
    mem = new Xvar* [rows];
    }
    catch (...) { assert (...) } 
    try {
    mem [0] = new Xvar [size];
    } catch (...) { assert (...) }
    for (i=1;i<rows;i++)
        mem [i] = &mem [0][i*cols];
    return mem;
}
```

or something like:

```
template <class Xvar> Xvar** New2 (unsigned int rows,unsigned int cols)
{
    try { 
    Xvar**  mem;
    unsigned int size, i;

    size = rows * cols;
    mem = new Xvar* [rows];
    mem [0] = new Xvar [size];
    for (i=1;i<rows;i++)
        mem [i] = &mem [0][i*cols];
    return mem;
     }catch  (...) { assert (...) }
}
```

I think, the second way is not recommended because, if the first new fails, mem is NULL,
so if we do mem [0] , we are accessing to a memory that is not allocated, so that application fails at that point, and error cannot be catched.

Comment: 1) If `new` fails, `mem isn't anything because it's out of scope, because `new` throws an exception when it fails (which you know because you're trying to catch it, I would think). 2) What's the point of catching an exception if you can't do anything with it? 3) Use `std::vector<>` 4) Stop worrying about performance before you even have your code working. Here you go: `int main(){}` the worlds fastest hosted C++ program! Get you anywhere?

Comment: What are you going to do after `new` fails?

Comment: @Victor Ruiz: when you say "the second way is not recommended", do you refer to "the second solution based on try-catch", or "the second code example from the question" (which is your *first* solution based on try-catch)?

Comment: now, i see, i´m silly. but if I want know what new fails, the first or the second, should I use the first solution or the second ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second way, if the first `new` fails, then evaluation immediately jumps to the catch block and never even tries to access `mem[0]`.

In any case, if you want to allow allocation to fail and detect this easily, you should probably use the `nothrow` variant, which simply returns `NULL` if the allocation fails. So something like

```
mem = new (nothrow) Xvar*[rows];
if (!mem) {
    // allocation failed, do whatever you want
}
mem[0] = new (nothrow) Xvar[size];
if (!mem[0]) {
    // allocation failed, do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: should I use , "nothrow" or "no throw"

Comment: @VictorRuiz: Use `(nothrow)`. The `(no throw)` was a typo that I already corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Don't catch the exception at all, just use RAII to clean up the memory when your function unwinds:

```
template <class Xvar> Xvar** New2 (unsigned int rows,unsigned int cols)
{
    unsigned int size = rows * cols;
    std::unique_ptr<Xvar*[]> mem(new Xvar* [rows]);
    mem[0] = new Xvar [size];
    for (i=1; i<rows; i++)
        mem[i] = &mem[0][i*cols];
    return mem.release();
}
```

- if the first `new` fails, your function didn't do anything and hasn't leaked any memory: `std::bad_alloc` is thrown and that's it
- if the second fails, the `unique_ptr` destructor takes care of that memory, so again you're ok.
- the next three lines can't throw, so nothing can cause the second allocation to leak

---

As GmanNickG pointed out, *this is still terrible code*. It's the terrible code you asked for, but I don't want to give the impression I endorse the original design. I don't. It's terrible.

Once the caller has successfully acquired their `Xvar**`, the only way to dispose of it this:

```
int **ii = New2<int>(x, y);
...
delete [] ii[0];
delete [] ii;
```

which is brittle and unpleasant. Two better designs are:

1. use a real matrix/2d-array template class which manages the storage, and can be returned by value. Then, the memory will be reclaimed when this value object goes out of scope
2. use a smart pointer with a custom deleter

   ```
   template <typename T> struct 2dDelete
   {
       void operator() (T **rows) {
           delete [] rows[0];
           delete [] rows;
       }
   };

   template <typename T>
   std::unique_ptr<T*[], 2dDelete<T>> 2dNew (unsigned rows, unsigned cols)
   {
       unsigned size = rows * cols;
       std::unique_ptr<Xvar*[]> tmp(new Xvar* [rows]);
       tmp[0] = new Xvar [size];
       for (i=1; i<rows; i++)
           tmp[i] = &tmp[0][i*cols];
       // hand-over from the intermediate pointer (which only owned the
       // top-level row allocation) to the caller's pointer (which will
       // own, and clean up, the whole thing).
       return std::unique_ptr<T*[], 2dDelete<T>> arr(mem.release());
   }
   ```

Comment: Of course, one should apply this everywhere, including the inner allocation and the return type.

Comment: The return type, anyway (I just stuck with OP's prototype). If the inner allocation throws though, it was never allocated, so this can't leak.

Comment: It can if nobody calls `delete` on it. Better to wrap it up and not worry.

Comment: if `new` throws `bad_alloc`, what is there to be deleted? If, instead, an `Xvar` default constructor throws, the compiler's still responsible for cleaning it up.

Comment: I'm talking about this line `mem[0] = new Xvar [size];`. Let's say you take out the `mem.release()` line; what deletes `mem[0]`?

Comment: But I haven't taken out that line. How can control leave the function without _either_ throwing (in which case the `[size]` array was never allocated and the `unique_ptr` cleans up the row array) _or_ calling release?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22474/discussion-between-gmannickg-and-useless)